# List comprehension not working

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I want to put the unique items from one list to another list, i.e eliminating duplicate items. When I do it by the longer method I am able to do it see for example.

```
>>>new_list = []
>>>a = ['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun']

>>> for word in a:
    if word not in a:
        new_list.append(word)

>>> new_list
['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'sun']
```

But when try to accomplish this using list comprehension in a single line the each iteration returns value "None"

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> a = ['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun']
>>> new_list = [new_list.append(word) for word in a if word not in new_list]
```

Can someone please help in understanding whats going wrong in the list comprehension.

Thanks in Advance
Umesh

Comment: `append` returns `None`, so that's what is added to the list. I think you need to review list comprehensions.

Comment: I think you meant `if word not in new_list`, not `if word not in a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a unique list of words, you can use `set()`.

```
list(set(a))
# returns:
# ['It', 'is', 'east', 'and', 'the', 'sun', 'Juliet']
```

If the order is important, try:

```
new_list = []
for word in a:
    if not a in new_list:
        new_list.append(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common
>   applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of
>   some operations applied to each member of another sequence or
>   iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a
>   certain condition.

Maybe you can try this:

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> a = ['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun']
>>> unused=[new_list.append(word) for word in a if word not in new_list]
>>> new_list
['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'sun']
>>> unused
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

**Notice:**

`append()` returns `None` if the inserted operation is successful.

Another way, you can try to use `set` to remove duplicate item:

```
>>> a = ['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun']
>>> list(set(a))
['and', 'sun', 'is', 'It', 'the', 'east', 'Juliet']
```

Comment: Fast answer. I'm writing almost the same things. +1